# EMMS fetch music track data from online database like freedb or cddb?

Tags: emms

Does this functionality exist?

I would like to add missing metadata top files in my music library, similar to how itunes does it (with Gracenote's CDDB or freedb).

Comment: Me too. Did you ever get anywhere? In fairness I cant make head nor tail of the manual. I have a buffer with a load of filenames but no "meta" data.